# Set UTC when fixing naive datetimes with django.utils.timezone?

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

I'm using Django 1.9. I have a model with a DateTimeField:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

And I have some naive text datetimes that look like this:

```
str = "2017-05-18T16:38:23"
```

If I do this:

```
d = datetime.strptime(result['last_modified'],
                                  "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
mymodel.last_modified = dt_aware
```

I get a warning:

```
RuntimeWarning
439
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1430: 
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField CV.last_modified received a 
naive datetime (2015-04-07 09:09:20) while time zone support
is active.
```

So I'm trying this instead, but I'm aware that instead of current timezone I should really be using UTC, because I know the datestrings are UTC:

```
d = datetime.strptime(str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
dt_aware = tz.make_aware(d, tz.get_current_timezone())
mymodel.last_modified = dt_aware
```

How can I amend this to use UTC rather than current timezone? I don't want to disable timezone support in my app.

Comment: Try `pytz.UTC` instead of `tz.get_current_timezone()`.